# Implement WhatsApp like status

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, whatsapp

This is a question posted to ask android how to implement WhatsApp like Status feature. Currently I am using a ViewPager to show the pages. But the problem is I am unable to figure out the solution where we can add multiple views on a page, which includes both videos and images. Is there any way I do this exactly like WhatsApp. I also have list of users and each of users has their own list of images and videos. Currently I have tried using a library called [Momentz](https://github.com/bolaware/momentz). But the library isn't smooth enough.Suggest me the libraries and please put me in the direction to implement this feature.

Comment: have you got any solution for this or not!?

Comment: I have got a few. Not very efficient but I will try the one suggest answer once I finish my current tasks @BhoomikaPatel

Comment: you may find this helpful. Easy to implement. https://github.com/shts/StoriesProgressView

Comment: Thanks this is actually helpful. I have tried this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

> frameLayout where you can add both imageView and videoview in a frameLayout and starting showing them one by one this way you can achieve what you wish

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add three view pagers where each one for image, text and videos then set visibility of image and videos to gone in the Oncreate method. Also you'll create three adapters for each Viewpagers each one for image, text and videos And one Tablayout that will be set-up with the three Viewpagers. Then if  isText then Tablayout will setup with text Viewpager then image and video Viewpagers visibility will be set to gone

Comment: IL give it a shot thanks

Comment: You're very much welcome

Comment: Try this too if my previous explanation is complicated.  https://github.com/shts/StoriesProgressView